# Coldfusion record listing with multiple inputs

Tags: coldfusion

> Detail: The value isim cannot be converted to a number.
> The error occurred on line 11.

I got this error

```
<cfform id="sef" action="#request.self#?fuseaction=#module_name#.emptypopup_add_sef" method="post">
  <div data-repeater-list="">
      <div data-repeater-item="">
            <cfoutput>
               <input name="isim" type="text">
               <input name="soyisim" type="text">
             </tr>
            </cfoutput>
          <hr>
      </div>
  </div>
</cfform>



<cfloop collection="#attributes#" item="key">
    <cfset sef = ToString(attributes[key]["isim"])>
    <cfoutput>#sef#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: What does this command show you?  `<cfoutput>#sef#</cfoutput>`

Comment: value defined with <cfset>

Comment: Can you pls show the error exactly as it displays. If you have robust exception handling switched on (which you should, in dev), it'll tell you the exact line of code that is causing the error. None of the code you include here relates to the error you mention, as far as I can see. This is not helped by you not indicating what line 11 actually is...

Comment: <input name="isim" type="text">

 line 11.  When I write a number in it and send it, it gives this error

Comment: What happens if you dump `form.isim` before the error occurs? Is it an number? Is it a list? Trying to determine what you mean by "multiple inputs" in your title.